# libgdx MeshBuilder - why are so many methods deprecated?

Tags: libgdx

I'm playing around with [MeshBuilder](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/MeshBuilder.html) and I'm noticing that many of the methods are deprecated. Anybody know why these are deprecated and what's suggested to use instead?

[image: libgdx api]

Comment: They're moved to the shapebuilders package: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/shapebuilders/package-frame.html

Comment: thanks Xoppa. I am studying your articles, thank you !! Big fan :)